# how do i make it so that it takes the variable input and create a text file when it is done

Tags: batch-file, arraylist, user-input

i'm trying to make a program that lets you write something like a book or a todo list

this i an idea i just had

```
SET /P line1=""
SET /P adlne=[add another line? Y or N?]
IF "adlne"=="Y" 
GOTO :a
IF "adlne"=="N" 
GOTO :b
:a
SET /P line2=""
SET /P adlne=[add another line? Y or N?]
IF "adlne"=="Y" 
GOTO :a1
IF "adlne"=="N" 
GOTO :b
:b
set list = "line1, line2, line3"
(for %%a in (%list%) do (
   echo %%a
   echo/
)) > theFile.txt
pause
```

i expect it to take the input and when you awnser "N" is takes the input variables and put them in a file but when i awnser "N" it stops asamething with  "Y"

Comment: Variables in batch are called with the syntax `%variable%`. Right now, you're comparing two literal strings so both of your `if` statements will always be false and the script will continue and end up running `:a`.

Comment: The `GOTO` needs to be on the same line as the `IF` command.

Comment: Also do not put spaces on either side of the equals symbol in a `SET` command. The space before becomes part of the variable name and the space after becomes part of the value of the variable.

Comment: What about using a text editor like Windows Notepad or word processing applications like Wordpad or applications like Sticky Notes all available for free and installed already with Windows? In my opinion it is a stupid idea to code a batch file executed by Windows command processor designed for running commands and applications for text editing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

a Better version maybe? It would seriously be a tedious tool to use and it makes no sense at all, seeing as there are 100s of great editers out there, but anyhow:

```
@echo off
choice /C CA /M "Clean file or append to previous notes? "
if "%errorlevel%"=="1" type nul>theFile.txt
:write
set /P line=line :
echo %line% >>theFile.txt
echo/>>theFile.txt
choice /C YN /M "add another line? "
if "%errorlevel%"=="1" goto :write
pause
```